# posting data on https url through BlackBerry BrowserField in os5

Tags: blackberry

i am using blackberry browserfield to posting data on server,for that i am making an url and calling requestContent(url) method it is working fine.

But my problem is that while i am calling this url through requestcontent() method i am getting response as html file which is having form to post again, and this form is posting through script submit() method.this form data is getting send on https url which is written in action attribute of this form,  so the response form data is not able to post on that url
and i am getting error as **transport descriptor are not found**

please reply me if  any one knows.

thanks